# Set a marker clicking on map on android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

It's posible to set a marker on the user clicking position with googlemaps API for android?? I haven't found any example is not possible to do it?

Comment: I'm not even trying to be rude but there are literally tons of examples of doing this, there may even be one in the Google docs. Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: There are tones of examples to set static markers , but that I need is to set a marker on the clicked position and for this purpose I have to get the location of the clikecd point.

Comment: I think...firstly try to do on Map OnClickListner..which return Lat, Long ...as well as you can set Marker against Lat, Long.